# WooCommerce REST API v3 remote ordering and payment and sending all data into WP

Tags: php, woocommerce-rest-api

I started creating a program where we can browse products by category. Add items to our cart (in messenger) and update cart etc.

We have Stripe / PayPal already connected to our App and would like to handle everything on our end, in the app. Then, when the order is completed, send the entire order as the data array into WP.

A few questions since I'm stuck.

I'd use this part from the API docs:
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#create-an-order

```
<?php
$data = [
    'payment_method' => 'bacs',
    'payment_method_title' => 'Direct Bank Transfer',
    'set_paid' => true,
    'billing' => [
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'address_1' => '969 Market',
        'address_2' => '',
        'city' => 'San Francisco',
        'state' => 'CA',
        'postcode' => '94103',
        'country' => 'US',
        'email' => 'john.doe@example.com',
        'phone' => '(555) 555-5555'
    ],
    'shipping' => [
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'address_1' => '969 Market',
        'address_2' => '',
        'city' => 'San Francisco',
        'state' => 'CA',
        'postcode' => '94103',
        'country' => 'US'
    ],
    'line_items' => [
        [
            'product_id' => 93,
            'quantity' => 2
        ],
        [
            'product_id' => 22,
            'variation_id' => 23,
            'quantity' => 1
        ]
    ],
    'shipping_lines' => [
        [
            'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
            'method_title' => 'Flat Rate',
            'total' => 10
        ]
    ]
];

print_r($woocommerce->post('orders', $data));
```

I have some issues with that though. I haven't tested it yet because we use it on a live store, but I'd like to know some stuff that isn't mentioned anywhere. Except for when using a 3rd party plugin, which we don't want. We want to only use the native, clean WooCommerce plugin.

• Is it possible to use a payment method as the reference, even though it does not exist in WP itself? So, if we use Stripe to create and pay for the order in messenger even though Stripe itself isn't in use in our store, can we still push that as the payment reference in the $data array here:

```
'payment_method' => 'stripe',
'payment_method_title' => 'Offsite Payment Method',
```

I read you need to create the order first normally if you want to get the payment token, and then update the status after payment, but since we're doing the entire ordering and payment processing offsite (only utilizing the WooCommerce catalog) and want to shoot in the order after a successful ordering process outside of WP, I'm a bit puzzled.

There's a lot of info to be found about missing cart features unless you use something like cocart, which we don't want since we can't ask customers to all install another to be able to use our tool.

Anybody came across a similar use case?

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to use a payment method as the reference, even though it does not exist in WP itself?**

Yes, they are basically strings you can pass any data which is of string type it doesn't matter whether it exists in wp or not

And as you said "you need to create the order first normally if you want to get the payment token, and then update the status after payment"

This is true first you need to create order ..

**Why ?**

Because in most of the payment gateways there will be a field called orderId to bind order id with that transaction and to keep things clean it's used ...So you need to create an order first when you create the order you need to set the status to pending. Then you will get orderId now redirect the user to payment gateway. Once user comes back again update the order status to processing if it success or failure if it failed

Comment: thank you. I have come a longer way since my initial post. I can besicly do everything now, except one thing that isn't really great. A user has to enter their address twice, once in messenger, and then again in the Stripe webview. So, that said, I am leaning towards getting the payment done in an iframe on the woocommerce store itself. But, now I don't know how to get Woo to know WHO I am sending over, I need the correct payment URL. I saw it exists when you create an order but I need to retrieve it somehow. Any idea where that is, cant find it anywhere in the docs?

Comment: I noticed this URL in an unpaid order, if we can get that somehow, that would be great:
store_url/afrekenen/order-pay/1324/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_8N4n5ACi
Obviously the "afrekenen" should be a variable since this is Dutch for our version

Comment: You can customize this in paytm plugin I guess not completely but up to some extent ...